# .NET Core Radio button group is not getting passed to the controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Model:**

```
public class TaxCertificateMailing
{
    public IList<Report> SelectReports { get; set; } 

    public class Report
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model LandNav.Areas.Reports.Models.TaxCertificateMailing
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Tax Certificate Mailing List";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("TaxCertificateMailing", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "reportForm", @class = "report-form col-9" }))
{
<!--Start of the form body-->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label><b>Select the report to run:</b></label><br />
        @for (var x = 0; x < Model.SelectReports.Count; x++)
        {
            <input type="radio" asp-for="SelectReports" name="@reports" value="@Model.SelectReports[x].Selected" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectReports[x].Text"/>
            <b>@Model.SelectReports[x].Text</b>
        }
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TaxCertificateMailing(
        //IFormCollection form
        TaxCertificateMailing TCM
        )
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When the form is posted the SelectReports IList has a count of 0.  What is the best way to handle posting a radio button group using .net core?

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of the input field should be `@Model.SelectReports[x].Selected`.

Use the code below for the for loop;

```
@for (var x = 0; x < Model.SelectReports.Count; x++)
{
   <input type="radio" asp-for="SelectReports" name="@Model.SelectReports[x].Selected" value="@Model.SelectReports[x].Selected" />
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectReports[x].Text"/>
   <b>@Model.SelectReports[x].Text</b>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one value is selected at a time (which is how radio buttons are intended to be used), you have some issues with your models. I'd suggest this:

```
public class TaxCertificateMailing
{
    public TaxCertificateMailing()
    {
        Reports = new HashSet<Report>();
    }

    public int SelectedReportID { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

This assumes you're pulling these from some sort of database - change the identifier to whatever makes sense, updating SelectedReportID's type to match.

Then, your view would look something like this:

```
<form asp-action="TaxCertificateMailing" asp-controller="Reports" method="post" id="reportForm" class="report-form col-9">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select the report to run:</legend>
        @foreach (var report in Model.Reports)
        {
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="radio" asp-for="SelectedReportID" id="report-@(report.ID)" value="@report.ID" class="form-check-input" />
                <label for="report-@(report.ID)" class="form-check-label">@report.Text</label>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```